# Github Pages additional custom subdomains possible, besides blog and www?

Tags: github, github-pages, custom-domain

I created my github.io page. Additionally, I added a `www` subdomain, it worked well.

Now I want to add another custom subdomain with this scheme: `forename.rootdomain.com`. For that reason, I added another CNAME to my rootdomain and point `forename` also to my `surname.github.io` page. This results in

> 404: There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

Is it possible to add additional subdomains, besides `blog.` and `www.`? Additionally, is it possible without creating new repos with `gh-pages` branches?

I only want to maintain one GitHub page; not additional copies of it.

Comment: Did you read [Managing a custom domain for your GitHub Pages site](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-a-subdomain) and [Troubleshooting custom domains and GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-custom-domains-and-github-pages#custom-domain-names-that-are-unsupported)?

Comment: Sure, but it's not clearly stated that other domains besides blog or www are possible or not. Sure you can directly add your subdomain as apex for your github page but I want multiple subdomains not only one. Well I solved it with Iframes and multiple repos but this solution is not preferable..